# How to Load a 3D Object in OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I've been working with OpenGL ES 2.0 for a few weeks now to get the hang of it. I've purchased the OpenGLES 2.0 for Android Quickstart Guide (its awesome), and I've been using the [Learn OpenGL ES](http://www.learnopengles.com) tutorials.

I'm using Blender to model objects, and I believe there is a c++ parser for it. The problem is I've been using Java and have little experience with c++.

Is there a java equivalent I can use? If not, is there a suitable engine I can use? I've used unity before, but I want to try my hand at something more challenging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/developing-mobile-game-graphics-for-intel-architecture-based-android-tablets-part-1) I just had published.  It lists all of the best game engine options for Android and [part 2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/developing-mobile-game-graphics-for-intel-architecture-based-android-tablets-part-2) focuses on OpenGL ES solutions.  Some are tightly integrated with Blender and some are all-Java solutions.  There are a lot more options now than just Unity and many are open source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the work you've done in writing the articles. It was very concise and it helped me greatly in choosing an adequate tool to use. I've decided to try jPCT-AEE.